# how to find large files in command line windows for version 5.1

Tags: windows, command-prompt

How do I find large files in windows ver 5.1 command line?

For Windows ver 6.1, I can run the following command:

> forfiles /p c:\ /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 100000 echo @file
>   @fsize"

However what is the equivalent command for version 5.1 windows?

Appreciate your quick help!

(added quote marks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be run from command line

```
for /r c:\ %f in (*) do if %~zf gtr 100000 echo %f %~zf
```

To run it from batch file, change `%` with `%%`

EDIT - As stated in the comments, arithmetic in batch command lines have some limits on the operands. In this case, the `%~zf` (size of file referenced in `for` command) in the left part of the `if` command have no problems, but the value on the right size is limited to values from `-2147483647` to `2147483646`.

To handle it, if command is executed under an administrator account, `wmic` command can be used. The command in OP question can be written as

```
wmic datafile where "drive='c:' AND filesize>'100000'" get caption, filesize
```

Comment: I think this is limited to 2GB filesizes and will fail to report the file when the filesizes are over 2 GB.

Comment: @foxidrive: Tested on a set of 4GB movie files. `%~zf` works and `echo` shows the correct value. BUT the value on the right side of `gtr` is what can fail. This value can not be larger than `2147483646`. The `100000` in OP question is safe.

Comment: Yes, that's how I tested it. I suspected that the OP 100,000 is not the real figure.

Comment: @foxidrive: If it is not the real figure, the original command, for which a equivalent is searched, will fail in exactly the same way. The file size is retrieved via `forfiles`, but `gtr` test is the same.

Comment: True.  As long as the OP knows of the limit.

Comment: To make it spam less: `@for /r w:\ %f in (*) do @(if %~zf gtr 100000 echo %~zf  %f)`

Answer (score 1):

first search biggest directories in actual directory

```
diruse /* /m /c /, . |sort
```

cd to the chosen dir; you can use diruse again or
search biggest files in the chosen directory, which are more than 500MB for example:

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 500000000 echo @path @fsize bytes"
```

Comment: as said in the comment above, this won't work for files larger than 2GB

Answer (score 0):

For windows, I couldn't find one answer that suits me for command line, so i coded my answer in powershell.
Following code will help you find the list of files (more than 1 KB) in your desired path to scan.

#Run via Powershell

```
#$PathToScan refers to the directory where you want to find your files greater than 1 KB.
$PathToScan="E:\"
"Path to scan:`t $PathToScan"
$hash = $null
$hash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -path $PathToScan -recurse | Where-Object {
#If you want to find files greater than 1GB, replace all KB in this powershell script to GB.
($_.Length /1KB) -gt 2 
} | ForEach-Object {
$hash.add(
    $_.DirectoryName.Replace("$PathToScan","")+$_.Name,
    [math]::Round(($_.length/1KB),0))
}

$TableStyle = @{Expression={$_.Value}; Label="Size (KB)"; Width=10;  Alignment = 'Left'}, 
          @{Expression={$_.Name}; Label="Name"; Width=100}
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort Value -Descending| Format-Table -Property $TableStyle

Countdown 5

Function Countdown{
Param ($TimeInSec)
Do {
    Write-Host "$TimeInSec"
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $TimeInSec--
    }
    Until ($TimeInSec -eq 0)
}
```

> Or you may view my code here;
> [Find large files in KB for Windows]:
> https://github.com/worldpeacez0991/powershell

Hope my answer helps someone, have a great day ^ ^